# Google Compute Engine VM - set up SSH tunnel through Python using google cloud API?

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, ssh-tunnel

I'm able to use the following command to create a temporary SSH tunnel to my GCE VM through the terminal:

```
gcloud compute ssh tunnel --zone=us-central1-a -- -NL 5000:localhost:5000
```

What I'm trying to determine is whether this is also possible through the Google Cloud Python API using the `google.cloud.compute_v1.VpnTunnelsClient`. The intent is that a tunnel is created when needed by a Python script to communicate with its counterpart on the VM, then closed again automatically.

So far I have not been able to make much progress with the documentation. The following code returns an error related to a missing "resource" field:

```
from google.cloud import compute_v1

client = compute_v1.VpnTunnelsClient()
tunnel = compute_v1.VpnTunnel()

config = {"project": <my_project_name>, "region": "us-central1"}
client.insert(vpn_tunnel_resource=tunnel, **config)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/Desktop/Atom/TradierApp2/cloud_compute.py", line 11, in <module>
    client.insert(vpn_tunnel_resource=tunnel, **config)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/compute_v1/services/vpn_tunnels/client.py", line 1002, in insert
    response = rpc(
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 154, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 72, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/compute_v1/services/vpn_tunnels/transports/rest.py", line 726, in __call__
    raise core_exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/projectname/regions/us-central1/vpnTunnels: Required field 'resource' not specified
```

Is what I'm trying even possible with the API? Have I simply missed a page outlining the process?

Comment: The API you are trying to use interfaces with VPN Gateway, not Compute Engine. The CLI command `gcloud compute ssh tunnel` creates an SSH tunnel. There are a number of Python SSH libraries to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clarified by John in the comments; the API is not meant for this task. Instead, I was able to use the `sshtunnel` library to simply replicate the behavior of the gcloud command:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    "<server_ip>",
    ssh_username="<username>",
    local_bind_address=("0.0.0.0", 5000),
    remote_bind_address=("0.0.0.0", 5000),
)

server.start()

print(server.local_bind_port)  # show assigned local port -> 5000
print(server.is_active) # -> True

# Communicate with the server...

server.stop()
```

Comment: how did you pass gcp auth? I tried using `ssh_pkey` with gcp pvt key to no avail. I used compute engines' external ip as a `server_ip` (also tried domain name) .